# Remove lines containing same string

Tags: regex, perl

If a line `IN(..)` and a line `OUT(..)` have the same string in their parentheses, then remove the line `OUT(..)`.

My input file is like :

```
IN(ABC); 
IN(DEF);        
IN(FGH);        
OUT(QWE);       
OUT(ABC);       
OUT(DEF);
```

My desired output is:

```
IN(ABC);
IN(DEF);
IN(FGH);
OUT(QWE);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the assumption that all `IN(...)` lines are before the `OUT(...)` lines (i.e. sorted), the following should work:

```
my %in;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^IN\((.*?)\)/) {
        $in{$1} = 1;
    } elsif  (/^OUT\((.*?)\)/) {
        if ($in{$1}) {
            next;
        }
    }
    print $_;
}

__DATA__
IN(ABC);
IN(DEF);
IN(FGH);
OUT(QWE);
OUT(ABC);
OUT(DEF);
```

The idea is to use a hash to track which `IN` values have been used. Go through the data line by line, if it's an `IN` line, store the value and print the line. If it's an `OUT` line and it is not in the list of recognized `IN` values, print it as well, otherwise, skip it.

Comment: While that may work, it is all kinds of wrong. Please at least `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` and take a look at [perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html)

Comment: Why  is this "all kinds of wrong", doesn't it answer the question? Is it inefficient? Why should use strict/warnings for such a short snippet? There would be no warnings, it's just 11 lines of code.